# How to check whether table column of the binary type has a value?

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

The Download command is showing in front of all the rows, I want to show it to only those rows having PDF file attached in the database.

```
protected void gvupdationsummary_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(st);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select [name],[data] from [Pragati].[dbo].[Pragati_Status_Updations] where Pragati_no=@Pragati_no", con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pragati_no", gvupdationsummary.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text);
    SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        //Response.ContentType = dr["type"].ToString();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dr["name"].ToString());
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["data"]);
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give details of what decide whether there is PDF in your database or not?

Comment: bro, that is what i want to ask, that how should i check the pdf is attached or not, as the pdf is in binary format saved,

Comment: You probably need to explain your database/table structure so that others can understand bit more about it and then answer your question. Does "data" field represents PDF?

Comment: I am able to save pdf file in binary format in database, later i am calling all the rows in gridview , and adding a command field in gridview , now there are some files having pdf and some files are not having pdf attached. So i just want to check which row is having a pdf and the row having pdf will show the command button "download" and the rows having no pdf shall not show any download button

Comment: Ok, I've just answered your question now.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you show seems to do the actual PDF download already. There is nothing you can do there to **prevent** the showing of a download button or link.

Instead you need to change the SQL query that provides data for `gvupdationsummary`, and add a column such as `HasPDF` there, like this:

```sql
SELECT /* your columns */ ,
       CAST(CASE WHEN [data] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS HasPDF
FROM   ....
WHERE  ....
```

Then in your grid rendering code you can use the boolean value of **`HasPDF`** to decide if the Download button should be shown.

Using this approach you don't needlessly transfer all PDF binary data from your database to your application, every time the grid is being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQLDataReader`'s `IsDBNull` method to see whether the column contains non-existent or missing values.

```
ind idx = dr.GetOrdinal("data");
if (!dr.IsDBNull(idx))
{
   // set download link on to response.
}
else
{
}
```